# video and audio embed file won't stream, but download works. (images work too)

Tags: php

I have sample files uploaded on remote server, three types of files: images, videos, audios.

I am accessing them via `cURL` on my local page and forcing a download.

A problem is that images `<img src="?image" />` work, but audio and video files embed does not. I use an embed code for test purposes and such framework for embedding them is fairly enough.

Here is my php file **test.php**

```
<?php
function download($url)
{
    set_time_limit(0);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    $r = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    header('Expires: 0'); // no cache
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()) . ' GMT');
    header('Cache-Control: private', false);
    header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($url) . '"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($r)); // provide file size
    header('Connection: close');
    echo $r;
    exit;
}

if (isset($_GET['image']))
{
    $file = 'https://googledrive.com/host/0B_3oJnpnNoF9UjlkVUwtWE5CY0U/city.jpg';
    download($file);
}

if (isset($_GET['music']))
{
    $file = 'https://googledrive.com/host/0B_3oJnpnNoF9UjlkVUwtWE5CY0U/horse.mp3';
    download($file);
}

if (isset($_GET['video']))
{
    $file = 'https://googledrive.com/host/0B_3oJnpnNoF9UjlkVUwtWE5CY0U/mov_bbb.mp4';
    download($file);
}

?>

<img src="http://localhost/test.php?image" />

<br />

<audio controls height="100" width="100">
    <source src="http://localhost/test.php?music" type="audio/mpeg">
    <embed height="50" width="100" src="http://localhost/test.php?music">
</audio> 

<br />

<video width="320" height="240" controls>
   <source src="http://localhost/test.php?video" type="video/mp4">
   <object data="http://localhost/test.php?video" width="320" height="240">
   </object> 
</video>
```

If I go to a link `http://localhost/test.php?music` or `http://localhost/test.php?video` download starts though, so I mean these are working files (links are not down).

My problem is that I am unable to stream audio and video files this way, and I am in need of some modification of this code.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try changing your headers to appropriate headers for music and video? i.e `header content-type audio`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you've set wrong headers for files ? You're forcing them to download, while you want to display them...